# Cannot run addon after installation of web-ext on ubuntu 16.04 nodejs v4.2.6 npm 3.5.2

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, web-ext

when installing web-ext i got this two messages in the and of installation:

```
npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /web-ext/chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.2.4
```

after trying to start addon with `web-ext run` i get this messages

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'R_OK' of undefined
>       at fileIsReadable (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/web-ext/dist/webpack:/src/util/file-exists.js:24:42)
>       at _callee$ (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/web-ext/dist/webpack:/src/util/file-exists.js:28:11)
>       at tryCatch (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/web-ext/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:62:40)
>       at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.invoke [as _invoke] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/web-ext/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:296:22)
>       at GeneratorFunctionPrototype.prototype.(anonymous function) [as next]
>   (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/web-ext/node_modules/regenerator-runtime/runtime.js:114:21)
>       at step (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/web-ext/dist/webpack:/node_modules/babel-runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:17:1)
>       at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/web-ext/dist/webpack:/node_modules/babel-runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:35:1
>       at new Promise (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/web-ext/dist/webpack:/node_modules/core-js/library/modules/es6.promise.js:177:1)
>       at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/web-ext/dist/webpack:/node_modules/babel-runtime/helpers/asyncToGenerator.js:14:1
>       at fileExists (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/web-ext/dist/web-ext.js:13002:17)

Comment: Please add your nodejs and npm version. Maybe you have to up- or downgrade.

Comment: nodejs v4.2.6 npm 3.5.2 thanks!

Comment: Please try to update to at least the latest v6 of node. I recommend you to use >= v8, because the support for v6 is ending in 2019 and you can't use async/await. (https://github.com/nodejs/Release#release-schedule)

Comment: After curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_10.x | sudo -E bash -
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs everything works. Thanks Phil!

Comment: Nice to hear ;)

Comment: @someNameJustToAnswer If those commands worked for you, you can add them as an answer below, and mark it as accepted, to close out this question.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update to at least the latest v6 of node. I recommend you to use >= v8, because the support for v6 is ending in 2019 and you can't use async/await for example. (https://github.com/nodejs/Release#release-schedule)